# Why I see scss file in my chrome inspector?

Tags: css, sass

I have created sass project.
In my global.scss file I have 2 imports:

```
//Modules and Variables
@import "partials/base";

//Partials
@import "partials/tables";
```

When I compile the file I am expecting to see in google chrome inspector just global.css file but I see instead _base.scss and _tables.scss.

Why is it? The compilation of global.scss is correct and I can see all the global.css file.

Answer (score 9):

Because there are `map` files in your `CSS` folder like `*.css.map` and `*.scss.map`. It basically reverse maps the `global.css` which is being used by the browser to the constituent `.scss` files. They are there because it makes it helpful for a developer to debug and know exactly which `.scss` file the code is in. If you don't want them delete the `.map` files.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! :)